# FQL query for seeing page post impressions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Basicly what I am trying to do is to get the post impressions from a page that I am and admin for and own and from the Graph API explorer have permission to view the insights. However when i run this:

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=10151215628833061 AND metric='post_impressions' AND end_time=end_time_date('2012-12-7') AND period=0
```

I have set the object id to equal the to the posts id and the period to 0 which is lifetime but have no success.

All i get back is this:

```
{
 "data": [
 ]
}
```

Can not figure out whats wrong with this, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your `object_id` doesn't look like a post id. A post id typically looks like this: `213367312037345_516488068391933`

Comment: Yeah when the post id has a "_" in it the first part is the page id and the second part is the post id. If you go to the facebook.com/10151215628833061 it brings up the post im trying to use.

Comment: There is a handy rule to keep in mind when you're working with the Facebook API: **IT IS NOT CONSISTENT**. Just because something works on the front end or in one table DOES NOT mean it works that way somewhere else. FQL wants the whole id, complete with underscore.

Comment: Ok what do you think the post id is for this post ?

http://www.facebook.com/accent.clothing/posts/10151215628833061

Comment: Look at `82346848060/feed`. Your post_id is `82346848060_10151215911933061`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post was created yesterday, but you're asking for metrics as of a month ago. The post didn't exist then, so there is nothing to return.

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id= '82346848060_10151215911933061' AND
   metric='post_impressions' AND period=0
```

You want to quote the object ID just in case a post you're querying contains an underscore.

Comment: tried that still returns the same as i said in the question above tried a different post as well this one 

http://www.facebook.com/82346848060/posts/10151192758923061

Comment: Did you request the `read_insights` permission when you authenticated?

Comment: The comment has to be posted by the page, otherwise it doesn't work. Also, I didn't find how to get the number for a specific date. I always get no data when I add e.g. end_time=end_time_date('2013-01-31')

Comment: The best you can request is an `end_time` at least 2-4 days prior to the current date. Insights data isn't immediately available. Facebook has some very specific visibility rules, so not all user's data will be visible to the API.